# Vue notifications array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some problems returning an array of notifications.
I have one simple wizard form that works good, and if it's ok I'm returning success message with Toastification, that looks like so:

```
this.$toast({
                            component: ToastificationContent,
                            props: {
                                title: 'Product Added',
                                icon: 'PlusIcon',
                                variant: 'success',
                            },
                        })
```

And this works good. But problem is listing an array of error messages.
My backend returns errors like so:

```
{
    "response": false,
    "message": [
        "The sku has already been taken.",
        "The slug has already been taken."
    ]
}
```

So I need to catch messages and show to the client, so I tried something like this:

```
.catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response.data.message)

                        error.response.data.message.map(function(value, key) {
                             this.$toast({
                                component: ToastificationContent,
                                props: {
                                    title: 'Something bad happened',
                                    text: 'here must be a message from the array. How to catch it?',
                                    icon: 'XIcon',
                                    variant: 'danger',
                                },
                        })
                        });
                    });
```

But every time I tried using this it says like:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$toast' of undefined

Any ideas how to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

In your callback function you lose the context of this in order to get its context you can use an arrow function `()=>`:

```
 error.response.data.message.map((value, key)=> {
   ...
```

instead of

```
 error.response.data.message.map(function(value, key) {
  ...
```